# How can I use cp command in Mac OS terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, operating-system

When I run the following command in a Mac terminal

```
cp /etc/passwd
```

It outputs the following message:

```
usage: cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvX] source_file target_file
       cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvX] source_file ... target_directory
```

Which I don't understand.

How do I go about copying a file using the Mac terminal?

Comment: By typing it and its arguments into the terminal.

Answer (score 3):

`cp` stands for "copy" - you use this command to make a copy of a file.

For example, let's say you want to make a copy of source file `file1` and call this target file `file2`. In your command line you would type:

`cp file1 file2`

Thus, the contents of `file2` will be identical to `file1`

All those other letters you see pre-pended with `-` (ex. -R) are called flags. To use those, you would have to read the `man` pages of the respective command. In this case, you would have to read `man cp` to learn how to use the respective flag...and how to use the command in general (note: `man` pages can be hard to read for beginners)

(P.S. The reason the all those flags were shown in your initial `cp /etc/passwd` effort is because you used the command incompletely as you didn't name the target file you wanted the source file to make a copy of. To have used it correctly, you could have instead typed `cp /etc/passwd passwd-backup`)

Comment: Thanks. I got it

Comment: what if there is a space in the file or folders name?
it does not seem you can do...
`cp "/folder/file" "/folder/newfile" ` or something to that effect.   I tried backticks, double quotes, single quotes....and i get an error saying that the file doesn't exist but its clearly there..and i can't type the full name as there is a space in it (don't fault me for the name, its not mine)